# Form submit not working on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, forms, google-chrome, post, submit

I'm experiencing an issue with a booking form displayed on an hotel wordpress website.

It currently works on firefox and edge, but nothing to do with chrome...

Here is my website :
http://terranostra-ariege.com/

The booking form is the big grey block on the center : when you hit "Réserver", then you are redirected to the booking solution with the options you chose.

The form is made this way :

```
<div id="resa">
    <form id="AVP" method="post" action="http://www.secure-hotel-booking.com/Terranostra-Bellevue/2VW1/search" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" id="language" name="language" value="fr" />
        <input type="hidden" id="AVP_arrivalDate" name="arrivalDate" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="AVP_nights" name="nights" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="guestCountSelector" name="guestCountSelector" value="ReadOnly" />

    <div class="resa_inline_block">
        <label for="AVP_list_days" class="resa_block_label"><?php _e('Arriv&eacute;e','qns'); ?> :</label>
        <select id="AVP_list_days" onchange="updateDDay();" class="days"></select>
        <select id="AVP_list_months" onchange="setDays();" class="months"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="resa_inline_block">
        <label for="AVP_list_nights" class="resa_block_label"><?php _e('Nombre de nuits','qns'); ?> :</label>
        <select id="AVP_list_nights"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="resa_inline_block">
        <label for="selectedAdultCount" class="resa_block_label"><?php _e('Adultes','qns'); ?> :</label>
        <select id="selectedAdultCount" name="selectedAdultCount"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="resa_inline_block">
        <label for="selectedChildCount" class="resa_block_label"><?php _e('Enfants','qns'); ?> :</label>
        <select id="selectedChildCount" name="selectedChildCount"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="resa_inline_block bb">
        <label for="selectedInfantCount" class="resa_block_label"><?php _e('B&eacute;b&eacute;s','qns'); ?> :</label>
        <select id="selectedInfantCount" name="selectedInfantCount"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="resa_inline_block">
        <input type="button" value="<?php _e('R&eacute;server','qns'); ?>" class="submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
      <p><?php _e('Contactez-nous au  <span style="font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;">05 61 05 52 06</span>  pour toute demande ou pour r&eacute;server directement','qns'); ?></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var months = new Array("janvier","février","mars","avril","mai","juin","juillet","août","septembre","octobre","novembre","décembre");
        var message='Date en dehors du planning';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.secure-hotel-booking.com/Terranostra-Bellevue/2VW1/scripts/base.js"></script>
</div>
```

I first thought it was because I was opening the form action on a new tab, and redirecting the user to an acknowledgments page on the current tab. So i tried to make it the right way with a simple link, and the problem is still there.

Moreover the chrome console is not reporting any error.

Do you have any idea about how I could solve this ?

Thank you very much in advance,

Elliott

Comment: The button you have used to submit the form is not actually a `type="submit"` button. I hope you are submitting the form via some javascript function. Well, the form did not work for me in any browser (chrome, firefox, IE, sarari, opera)

Answer (score 0):

Change your input button to `submit` rather than `button`:

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php _e('R&eacute;server','qns'); ?>" class="submit" />
```